# When to use 'get_category_by_path' vs. 'get_term_by' to get category object from `get_query_var( 'category_name' )`?

Tags: categories, terms, oop

I'd like to retrieve the category object from the category name, using the public query variable `category_name`, via `get_query_var( 'category_name' )`:

```
$cat = get_query_var( 'category_name' );
```

There appear to be two methods:

1. `get_category_by_path()`
2. `get_term_by()`

### Using `get_category_by_path()`

Based on WordPress core code ([`wp-includes/canonical.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/canonical.php)), I found out that I'd do it this way:

```
$category = get_category_by_path( $cat );
```

### Using `get_term_by()`

Now, as I see it, I can also get the category object like this:

```
$category = get_term_by( 'slug', $cat, 'category' );
```

### Retrieving the Category object

Then use the category object (held by `$get_category` variable) like so:

```
if( $category && !is_wp_error( $category ) ) {
    $get_category = $category;
}

// Just an example of what could be done
if( isset($get_category) ) {       
   echo 'Current category: ' . $get_category->name;
}
```

What are the differences between the two methods? What advantages does one have over the other, and in what situations should one be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correct @its_me. The latter, `get_term_by()` would be the best way, In my opinion <s>, as I believe `get_category_by_path` uses `get_term_by`, just prepopulating the taxonomy to be `category`</s>.

Edit: As I mentioned in my comment, `get_category_by_path` is much less efficient, since it gets multiple terms,. and then compares the hierarchical path. `get_term_by` is much better.

Comment: Actually, `get_category_by_slug` uses `get_term_by` not `get_category_by_path`, or am I missing something? (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/category.php)

Comment: Nope, you are correct. Actually `get_category_by_path` is much less efficient, since it gets multiple terms,. and then compares the hierarchical path. `get_term_by` is much better.